# wolftpm all time recieving TPM_RC_BAD_TAG

Tags: cryptography, embedded, stm32, spi, tpm

Trying to use infenion slb9670 with wolftpm. When porting lib to custom spi functions and os recieving 0x01e(dec 30) which means TPM_RC_BAD_TAG. Is my Spi connection correct if I have already received caps? 
(Same code works fine on STM32f7 board with STM HAL spi implementation)
Thanks

```
rc = TPM2_Init(&tpm2Ctx, TPM2_IoCb, userCtx);
if (rc != 0) 
{
    tst_printf("\r\nTPM init failed! rc = %i;", rc);
    break;
}
else
{
    tst_printf("\r\nTPM init success!");
    tst_printf("\r\nTPM2: Caps 0x%08x, Did 0x%04x, Vid 0x%04x, Rid 0x%2x \n",
    tpm2Ctx.caps,
    tpm2Ctx.did_vid >> 16,
    tpm2Ctx.did_vid & 0xFFFF,
    tpm2Ctx.rid);
}
/* define the default session auth */

XMEMSET(tpm_session, 0, sizeof(tpm_session));
tpm_session[0].sessionHandle = TPM_RS_PW;
TPM2_SetSessionAuth(tpm_session);
if (rc != TPM_RC_SUCCESS &&
    rc != TPM_RC_INITIALIZE /* TPM_RC_INITIALIZE = Already started */ ) {
    tst_printf("TPM2_SetSessionAuth failed 0x%x: %s\n", rc, TPM2_GetRCString(rc));
    break;
}

Startup_In startup;
XMEMSET(&startup, 0, sizeof(Startup_In));
startup.startupType = TPM_SU_STATE;
rc = TPM2_Startup(&startup);
if (rc != TPM_RC_SUCCESS &&
    rc != TPM_RC_INITIALIZE /* TPM_RC_INITIALIZE = Already started */ ) {
    tst_printf("TPM2_Startup failed %i: %s\n", rc, TPM2_GetRCString(rc));
    //break;
}

tst_printf("\r\nTPM2_Startup pass!\f");
```

**Output:**

```
TPM init success!
TPM2: Caps 0x30000697, Did 0x001b, Vid 0x15d1, Rid 0x10
TPM2_Startup failed 30: Unknown
```

**edited**

Values of cmd in TPM2_TIS_SendCommand:

```
80 01 00 00 00 0c 00 00 01 44 00 00             (working example)
00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 01 44 00 00             (my case)
```

**80 01** - **TPM_ST_NO_SESSIONS** which has to be added by **TPM2_Packet_Finalize**!

Comment: `TPM_RC_BAD_TAG` is in the title but nowhere in the question.

Comment: Edited. Response code 30 means TPM_RC_BAD_TAG.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake was in functions which are preparing packet. My version of IAR compiler cannot handle __REV() for 16 bit values. I used small macro for handling, now everything works fine.